# Typescript base class reference subclass

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a tree-like structure with inheritance like the following:

`base.ts`:

```
export class BaseClass {
    children: BaseClass[] = [];

    get subclassChildren(): SubClass[] {
        return this.children.filter((child): child is SubClass => child instanceof SubClass);
    }
}
```

`sub.ts`:

```
import { BaseClass } from './base';
export class SubClass extends BaseClass {}
```

This wont work because the base class cannot find `SubClass`:

> ```
> TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
> base.ts(4,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SubClass'.
> base.ts(5,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SubClass'.
> base.ts(5,78): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SubClass'.
> ```

Not unexpected but if I try to import the subclass in `base.ts` it wont work either as there are circular references to each other:

> ```
> TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
> ```

Is there a way to forward declare `SubClass` or some other way to get this code working?

**EDIT:**

`tsconfig.json` (generated by `tsc --init`):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) it is possible to add methods and properties to existing classes:

`base.ts`:

```
export class BaseClass {
  children: BaseClass[] = [];
}
```

`sub.ts`:

```
import { BaseClass } from './base';

export class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    foo(){
        console.log('foo');
    }
}

/* augment base class */
declare module "./base" {
    interface BaseClass {
        subclassChildren: SubClass[];
        bar(): void;
    }
}

/* implement getter */
Object.defineProperty(BaseClass.prototype, 'subclassChildren', {
    get(){
        return this.children.filter((child: BaseClass): child is SubClass => child instanceof SubClass);
    },
});

/* implement method */
BaseClass.prototype.bar = function bar(){
    console.log('bar');
}
```

When using it both `base.ts` and `sub.ts` has to be imported as only `sub.ts` contains the augmented class:

```
import { BaseClass } from './base';
import { SubClass } from './sub';

const root = new BaseClass();
root.children.push(new BaseClass());
root.children.push(new SubClass());

root.subclassChildren.map((child) => child.foo());
root.bar();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**base.ts:**

```
    export class BaseClass {
        className = "base"
        children: BaseClass[] = [];
        get subclassChildren() {
            return this.children.filter((child) => { return child.className == "subClass" });
        }
    }
```

**sub.ts:**

```
import { BaseClass } from './base';
export class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    className = "subClass"
}
```

Comment: The major issue here is that `subclassChildren` is not available on `BaseClass` any longer. And since `children` is still an array of `BaseClass` it would need a lot of casting.

Comment: And in this way?

Comment: This will filter out the subclasses but not cast them any longer, what I get is no longer a `SubClass[]` but a `BaseClass[]`.